# How to move an image with pseudo-elements?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get an image moving like it's hovering off the page for a little bit, making it move up a little bit higher than where it currently is when hovering the mouse over it.

It should get into the position where I have the .thumbnailhover sticking right now. I am probably not applying the `::after` properly enough, but I cannot seem to figure out how to do it. Both the image + thumbnailfade should get on the same positon.

```css
.thumbnail {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  height: 332px;
  width: 450px;
}

.thumbnail::after {
  transform: translate(0px);
}

.thumbnailfade {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  height: 332px;
  width: 450px;
  opacity: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 3em;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.thumbnail:hover .thumbnailfade {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(10px, -10px);
}

.thumbnail::after:hover {
  transform: translate(10px, -10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail">
  <div class="thumbnailfade">
    Oh my god!
  </div>
</div>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/m5vf1j0q/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your request. But is this what you want:

```css
.thumbnail {
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
    height: 332px;
    width: 450px;
}

.thumbnail::after{
    transform: translate(0px);
}

.thumbnailfade {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    height: 332px;
    width: 450px;
    opacity: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 3em;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.thumbnail:hover .thumbnailfade{
    opacity: 1;
}

.thumbnail:hover {
    position: relative;
    transform: translate(10px, -10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail"> 
    <div class="thumbnailfade">
        Oh my god!
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i am a add transition: 0.4s; in .thumbnail class for smooth hover.